# ext.flutter.driver" is not found in "extensionRPCs" and Cannot connect to the Dart Observatory URL ws://127.0.0.1:40615/q2l5tFCaOOs=/ws

Tags: java, android, flutter, automation, appium

I have added the following snippet inside main.dart file of my flutter android project

```
enableFlutterDriverExtension(
  commands: [],
  finders: [],
);
```

runApp(const AppRepoProvider());
also added the following snippet inside pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter_driver:
  sdk: flutter
```

and build debug apk by running the following command

```
flutter build apk --debug
```

after running this in appium inspector, got the above error
But, for UIAutomator2 , appium inspector is working properly. how to use flutter appium driver here properly